# How can I pass Spark's accumulator to a function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, accumulator, bigdata

I want to do something like this.

```
val ac = sc.accumulator(0)
....
a = a.map(x => someFunction(x, the_accumulator_object))
....
```

What should be in the place of `the_accumulator_ojbect` in the code above? Would writing `ac` there be just fine?

Also, in the function

```
def someFunction(x: TypeOfX, a: TypeOfAccumulator) : ReturnType =
{
    .....
}
```

What should be in the place of `TypeOfAccumulator` in the function above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additional info about Spark accumulators can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators)

According to the scala-docs regarding the creation of the accumulator:

> /**    * Create an [[org.apache.spark.Accumulator]] variable of a
>   given type, with a name for display    * in the Spark UI. Tasks can
>   "add" values to the accumulator using the `+=` method. Only the    *
>   driver can access the accumulator's `value`.    */

The default accumulator type is `int`. You can set your own type though, but need to properly implement the `+=` method to add values to your own accumulator type:

```
val ac = sc.accumulator[MyOwnType](MyOwnTypeObject, "my own type object accumulator")
```

Your main code fragment will be like:

```
val ac = sc.accumulator(0, "some accumulator")
....
a = a.map(x => someFunction(x, ac))
....
System.out.println("My accumulator value is: " + ac.value)
```

Where the `someFunction` method implantation will be like:

```
def someFunction(x: TypeOfX, ac: Accumulator[Int]) : ReturnType =
{
    ...
    ac += 1
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is that second parameter in the declaration of the accumulator? Is that for identifying different accumulators? Secondly, can I use any type with an accumulator. For example, i want to use Set type with it.

Comment: Edited the answer with answers to your questions.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I will try your solutions.

Comment: I am trying this, but its failing -> val ac = sc.accumulator[Set[Integer]](Set.empty[Integer], "set1_acc"), saying that it could not find implicit value for parameter param: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam[scala.collection.multable.Set[Integer]]. Any idea, what mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Try doing: `val ac = sc.accumulator[Set[Integer]](Set[Integer](), "set1_acc")`